# Create non associated records with changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm working on creating a local db schema for a remote API, and I have some problems.

```
# CatalogObject
schema "catalog_objects" do
  field :type, :string

  has_one :item_data, ItemData, foreign_key: :catalog_object_id
  has_one :item_variation_data, ItemVariationData, foreign_key: :catalog_object_id
end

# ItemData
schema "item_data" do
  field :name, :string
  ...

  belongs_to :catalog_object, CatalogObject
end

# ItemVariationData
schema "item_variation_data" do
  field :name, :string
  ...

  belongs_to :catalog_object, CatalogObject
end

# API Response
%{
  "id" => "UA3XRLH75LEFRXCF2YWEUKB",
  "item_data" => %{
    "name" => "NY Steak",
    "variations" => [
      %{
        "id" => "2DYQSRC4AUZGAMCFTCOD24Q",
        "item_variation_data" => %{
          "item_id" => "UA3XRLH75LEFRXCF2YWEUKB",
          ],
          "name" => "Regular",
        },
        "type" => "ITEM_VARIATION",
      }
    ],
  },
  "type" => "ITEM",
}
```

I'm able to create `item_data` based on the `type` being *ITEM* without any problem with `create_catalog_object/1`, but I don't know where to start with the data in `variations` since they are supposed to be casted as `CatalogObject` with `type` being *ITEM_VARIATION*.

I would like to create Item CatalogObject with ItemData and ItemVariation CatalogObject with ItemVariationData in one go, but I couldn't use `put_assoc` or `cast_assoc` in `ItemData.changeset` since `ItemData` is not related to `ItemVariation CatalogObject`

Is there a way to create all the records in one go?

Sorry if I didn't explain the problem correctly.

Comment: Why does your `CatalogObject` have a 1-to-1 relationship with `ItemVariationData`? Based on your API response, I assume that 1 `CatalogObject` has 1 `ItemData`, which has many `ItemVariationData` models. If you'd model it like this, you could create first the `CatalogObject`, then the `ItemData` and then many `ItemDataVariation` models.

Comment: It's how the API constructed. I'm simply modeling after the API. `CatalogObject` can be many types, I only listed out `ITEM` and `ITEM_VARIATION`, there are `CATEGORY`, `IMAGE` ... and all of them have their corresponding data objects. And yes, I have been creating `CatalogObject` first then the data, which makes the associated objects more complicated

Answer (score 1):

After giving some thought about this, would this work for you?

```
defmodule ItemData do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "item_data" do
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :catalog_object, CatalogObject
    has_many :variations, CatalogObject
  end

  def changeset(item_data, params \\ %{}) do
    item_data
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> put_assoc(:variations, Map.get(params, :variations, []))
  end
end

defmodule ItemVariationData do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "item_variation_data" do
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :catalog_object, CatalogObject
  end

  def changeset(item_data, params \\ %{}) do
    item_data
    |> cast(params, [:name])
  end
end

defmodule CatalogObject do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "catalog_objects" do
    field :type, :string

    # The on_replace option tells Ecto that it is okay to update these fields
    # with a put_assoc or cast_assoc in a changeset.

    has_one :item_data, ItemData, on_replace: :update
    has_one :item_variation_data, ItemVariationData, on_replace: :update
  end

  def changeset(item_data, params \\ %{}) do
    item_data
    |> cast(params, [:type])
    |> put_assoc(:item_data, Map.get(params, :item_data))
    |> put_assoc(:item_variation_data, Map.get(params, :item_variation_data))
  end
end

# Example for how to create a CatalogObject struct from your API response
catalog_object = %CatalogObject{
  type: "ITEM",
  item_data: %ItemData{
    name: "NY Steak",
    variations: [
      %CatalogObject{
        type: "ITEM_VARIATION",
        item_variation_data: %ItemVariationData{
          name: "Regular"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

# Wherever you want to create the CatalogObject
catalog_object
|> CatalogObject.changeset() 
|> Repo.insert()
```

Comment: I can see how this would work out for the purpose of just importing data. The association `variations` on `item_data` would never be used except during the data import. I was planning on just importing `ITEM` type first, and then `ITEM_VARIATION` type. I'm gonna give this a shot. Thanks.